# demarcating a value on sns.heatmap()

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap

I'm plotting the magnitude of a physiological response (z) as a function of trial (y) and time sample within the trial (x). I'm wondering if it's possible to add to each row (for each trial) a point indicating the reaction time for that trial.

```py
def plot_evoked_response_map(ordered_samples_df, fig_name,
                             fig_path=fig_path, trial_end_sample_idx=1500):

    jtplot.style('grade3', context='poster', fscale=1.4, spines=False, gridlines='--')

    ordered_samples_df = ordered_samples_df.loc[ordered_samples_df.trial_sample < trial_end_sample_idx]

    samples_sparse = ordered_samples_df[['trial_sample', 'trial_epoch',
    'z_pupil_diameter']]

    samples_sparse['reset_trial_epoch_idx'] = np.repeat(np.arange(0,n_trials), 
                                                    trial_end_sample_idx)    
    # hack to get pivot to respect the stated order of the trial epochs 
    # otherwise, will sort the index ... 

    samples_pivot = samples_sparse.pivot(index='reset_trial_epoch_idx',
    columns='trial_sample', values='z_pupil_diameter') 

    plt.figure(1)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))     
    sns.heatmap(samples_pivot, fmt="g", cmap='viridis',
    cbar_kws={'label': 'pupil diameter'}, robust=True, vmin=0, vmax=2)
    plt.title(fig_name)
    plt.ylabel('trial')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(fig_path, fig_name + '.png'))

    return fig_name

_= plot_evoked_response_map(rt_ordered_samples_df, fig_name='RT_ordered_evoked_responses')
```

[sample of the type of plot i'm generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxzsh.png)

Comment: can you add a sample of your data? We can't reproduce based on the code you supplied. What plot comes out of it and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @cripcate thanks for responding! i've added a link to the plot i'm generating. i don't feel comfortable sharing a sample of the data. for the plot that i linked to, trials are plotted in ascending order according to the value of the reaction time for that trial. what i would like to do is plot a point for every row showing the reaction time for that trial. hope this is still helpful supplementary information!

Comment: @cripcate Figured the problem out! Thanks for your help so far.